# Why is %s treated as character. why such unusual behavior of string as a pointer

Tags: arrays, pointers

```
int main()
{

 char *arr="hello";
 clrscr();
 printf("%s",arr);
 arr="";

  printf("and %s",arr+2);
 getch();

 return 0;
}!
```

OUTPUT OF THIS CODE:-

helloand nd %s

check it here:-
http://ideone.com/TJzUvp

// why this unusual behaviour with the pointer string?

Comment: what is you trying to do??? arr+2 is an invalid location

Comment: but why such invalid output??
even if i do : arr="y"
same ouput is seen

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking undefined behaviour.

Referring to `arr+2` after setting `arr=""` is picking up an arbitrary piece of memory (in this case, a piece of one of your string literals).

Answer (score 1):

When you run the program the memory is laid out so that the constant string `and %s` comes right after the constant empty string. The memory looks like this:

```
.  .  .  \0  a  n  d  ' '  %  s \0  .  .  .
```

When you assign the empty string to `a`, you make `a` point to the `\0` character. Then you calculate a+2, and the result points to the `n` character.

Therefore, when you interpret a+2 as a NUL-terminated string you get `nd %s`.

This is, of course, undefined behaviour. Many compilers lay out constants so that they are in the order that you use them: here the empty string comes before `and %s`. But nothing forces the compiler to do so, and if it lays out the memory differently you would get different results. The program could even crash.

Comment: But why is it always taking from the string in the printf()??..
my array arr="" doesn't point the first index('\0' acc. to u) of the printf string

Comment: No, it points to the 0-byte just before the argument to `printf`, which makes an empty string. If you add one, `a+1`, you get the address of one byte past the zero, which is `a`. If you add two, `a+2`, you get the address of `n`.  Understand?

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a pointer to a string>.. You created a block in the memory space meant for Global Variables and constants..and used a pointer to point to that block..You can't change the value because it is a part of CONSTANT memory space...what you are doing is reassigning the pointer to another memory location and expecting to be lucky to point to a desired location..it wont always happen